# NotSupportedError at / deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

Tags: python, django, sqlite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Django application using the default SQLite database to Elastic Beanstalk. The application works fine locally, however, on server, I get the error as : [image]

Any idea what's wrong? Can we not deploy SQLite app on AWS EBS?

Here is my project structure that is getting deployed

```
├── .ebextensions
│   ├── django.config
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── app
│   │       ├── app.js
│   │       ├── logo.svg
│   │       └── style.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── app
│   │       ├── hello.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       └── job_detail.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── env
│   ├── All Virtual env related files
├── images
│   ├── Photo_on_5-9-14_at_2.31_PM.jpg
│   ├── Photo_on_5-9-14_at_2.32_PM.jpg
│   └── Photo_on_5-9-14_at_2.32_PM_v4McLzE.jpg
├── myproject-test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── staticfiles
│   |-- All static files collected using collectstatic
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── logo.svg
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── subscribe
│       ├── email-icon.png
│       ├── main.css
│       └── main.js
├── subscribe
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── form.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_subscribe_option_alter_subscribe_email_and_more.py
│   │   ├── 0003_alter_subscribe_option.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── subscribe
│   │       ├── email-icon.png
│   │       ├── main.css
│   │       └── main.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── subscribe
│   │       ├── subscribe.html
│   │       └── thank_you.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── templates
│   └── base.html
├── upload
│   └── images
│       ├── Photo_on_5-9-14_at_2.31_PM.jpg
│       └── Photo_on_5-9-14_at_2.31_PM_3.jpg
└── uploads
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── images
    │   └── Photo_on_5-9-14_at_2.31_PM_3.jpg
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_uploadfile.py
    │   ├── 0003_alter_uploadfile_file.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── uploads
    │       ├── add_file.html
    │       └── add_image.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Deployment process:

1. Zip all the necessary files
2. Create AWS EBS application with Python
3. Add environment variables
4. Create app and access URL

Please help.

Comment: You're using a very old and outdated version of sqlite.

Comment: How? I have installed latest version of Python. Created virtual env and installed latest version of Django. If everything is latest how can sqlite be old? I haven't installed sqlite seperately

Comment: Upgrade the OS. Or manually install an up to date copy of the sqlite library somewhere Python will see it. If you search here there's a ton of questions about it.